# Polymorphic Association routes going backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue with my polymorphic associations. The edit link appears in my view page just fine when using this code `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_blog_comment_path(comment) %>`. I'm trying to enable the editing of a comment, in this case one that belongs to the blog. However, the link actually points to `.../blogs/7/comments/3/edit` when it should be the reverse. The blog id is 3 and the comment id is 7. It is this way for all comments. I'm stuck finding where the error is. What is causing them to swap?

My routes:

```
blog_comments GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PATCH  /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         PUT    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                   blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)                            blogs#index
                         POST   /blogs(.:format)                            blogs#create
                new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)                        blogs#new
               edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)                   blogs#edit
                    blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#show
                         PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#update
                         PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#update
                         DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#destroy
```

And my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  def allowed_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id)
  end
end
```

My _comments.html.erb. If the second half looks ugly, it is because I could not for the life of me get the @commentable variable to work with the edit and delete paths so I just made a conditional statement.

```
<div id="articles-wrapper">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <div class="articles">
        <div class="post-title"><%= comment.content.html_safe %></div>
        <div class="date">Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago by <%= link_to comment.user.username, user_path(comment.user) %>

          <% if @commentable = @blog %>
            <%= link_to edit_blog_comment_path(comment) do %><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><% end %>
            <%= link_to blog_comment_path(comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %><i class="fa fa-times"></i><% end %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to edit_article_comment_path(comment) do %><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><% end %>
        <%= link_to article_comment_path(comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %><i class="fa fa-times"></i><% end %>
          <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `edit_blog_comment_path` expects a `blog_id` and an `id` for the comment (`/blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id/edit`). Wherever you're generating the broken link, inspect the two ids that you're passing to the url helper and make sure they are correct. I don't see anywhere in your code that you're grabbing the blog object from the params (e.g. `@blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])`).

Comment: Wouldn't that be what the load_commentable does? I've edited my question to include routes.rb.

Comment: I edited your question to remove irrelevant code. All `load_commentable` does is populate the `@commentable` variable - you still need to use it. Please post the code (likely from your `index.html.erb` view that generates the edit link (`edit_blog_comment_path(comment)`). This is where your issue is. You need to pass both the `blog_id` and the comment [`id`] to the `edit_blog_comment_path` helper.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if the routes file would be necessary. I've added the view partial to my question.

Comment: I managed to find the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the link_to in the view file to include both elements instead of just the one.

```
<%= link_to edit_blog_comment_path(@blog, comment) do %>
```

Then in the comments controller make sure the comment instance variable is set like so for whatever method you're using it in.

```
  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
```